# Button is behind the ListView in FrameLayout

Tags: android, xml, listview, android-framelayout

I have a FrameLayout that consists of a list view and a button. The whole point of the FrameLayout is that elements that are after other elements will be displayed above them.

Since the button code is below the ListView code, I expected the button will always be on top, but it isn't. I can't figure it out - as soon as I get enough items in my list, the button is underneath it and it becomes obsolete.

**XML:**

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvMovies"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:elevation="3dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAddMovie"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/raised_action_button"
        android:elevation="5dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="+"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="30sp" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `elevation` property from the list view. That's it.

It seems like the elevation causes the element to be on top of other elements.

Answer (score 1):

From developer.android:

> FrameLayout is designed to block out an area on the screen to display
>   a single item. Generally, FrameLayout should be used to hold a single
>   child view,

The current dimensions of the framelayout is the entire screen.  If I was to use the entire screen for the above layout I would do something like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="5"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvMovies"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:elevation="3dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal">    

<Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAddMovie"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/raised_action_button"
        android:elevation="5dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="+"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="30sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

You can say 0dp weight for either a height or a width, but not both.  You then team it up with a layout_weight.  In this case the first nested linear layout takes up 5/6ths of the screen, the second 1/6th.  Thus your button sits in a protected space that the list view will not block out.

The outer linear layout has a vertical orientation which makes the two inner layouts stack on top of each other, the inners are horizontal to make them go across the entire screen.  You will need to tweak those weights to make it work for you.

Comment: Thanks! However, I tried your solution and the button is still behind the list view.

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me reading the above xml.  Are you modifying the layouts or button in your code?

If not, here are some things to try:
Go back to a simpler layout that works. Then add back and find out whats breaking it.  

Strip out a bunch of the settings of the button like layout_gravity, gravity.  This just eliminates them as possible sources of the problem.

For the outer layouts, change the background colors so you can see their boundaries or add borders. Then you can see what your actual layouts are.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to remove things and I found that the `elevation` on the list view was causing the problem. However, I still want the list view to cast shadow. How can I do that without elevation?

Comment: Google : android listview shadow effect 
You will get a bunch of links with different methods.  Find one you like.

Answer (score 0):

You can use RelativeLayout for this. If you want button view over the listview android:layout_above="@+id/btnAddMovie" delete this line.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/content_frame"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lvMovies"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btnAddMovie"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:elevation="3dp"
    android:paddingTop="8dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnAddMovie"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:elevation="5dp"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="+"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="30sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```